# Boolean to String in Java

Tags: java

How do I make this program stop and go back to turn the tv on and off?

If the OFF is chosen I want it to show the current status of the TV.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TvTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String x;
        String y;
        boolean tvStatus = false;
        int chan;
        int volu;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        TV tv2 = new TV(false,2,10);

        // Print out the current status of our TV
        System.out.print(tv2);
        System.out.println();

             System.out.print("Turn TV On or Off ?");
             x = input.nextLine();

             if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("on"))
               {
                   tvStatus = true;

               }else if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("off"))
               {
                   tvStatus =false;
               }

            System.out.print("Change the Channel to : ");
            chan = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Increase the volume by 1 or Decrease by -1 : ");
            volu = input.nextInt();

            TV tv1 = new TV(tvStatus,chan,volu);

            if(volu == 1)
            {
                tv1.incrementVolume();

            }else if (volu == -1)
            {
                tv1.decrementVolume();
            }

            System.out.println(tv1);


    }
}// ENd of TvTest
```

here is my tv class 
i think there should be way to improve the toString method or even my setter

```
public class TV
{
    private boolean flag = false;
    private int ch;
    private int vol = 10;

    public TV(boolean onOffSwitch, int channel, int volume)
    {
        this.setFlag(onOffSwitch);
        this.setCh(channel);
        this.setVol(volume);
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean onOffSwitch)
    {
        if(onOffSwitch == true)
        {
            flag = true;
        }else
        {
            flag = false;
        }

    }// End of setFlag

    public boolean getFlag()
    {
        return flag;
    }// End of getFlag

    public void setCh (int newChannel)
    {
        if (newChannel >= 99)
        {
            ch = 99;
        }else
        {
            ch = newChannel;
        }

        if(newChannel < 0)
        {
            ch = 1;
        }
    }//end of setCh

    public int getCh ()
    {
        return ch;
    }// End of getCh

    public void setVol(int newVolume)
    {
        if(newVolume >= 20)
        {
            vol = 20;
        }

    }// End of SetVolume

    public void incrementVolume()
    {
        vol++;
    }

    public void decrementVolume()
    {
        vol--;
    }

    public int getVol()
    {
        return vol;
    }// ENd of getVolume

    public String toString()
    {
        if(flag == false)
        {
            return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched","OFF","TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
        }else
        {
            return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched","ON","TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
        }

    }

}// End of TV class
```

Comment: Why are you not happy about toString ??

Comment: Corrected your setFlag method ... What is wrong with your toString method ? Is it too slow ? Doesn't it write what you expected ?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly your question is.

Answer (score 3):

First, this one :

```
public void setFlag(boolean onOffSwitch)
    {
        if(onOffSwitch == true)
        {
            flag = true;
        }else
        {
            flag = false;
        }

    }
```

Should be :

```
public void setFlag(boolean onOffSwitch)
    {
        flag = onOffSwitch;
    }
```

Then :

```
public void setCh (int newChannel)
    {
        if (newChannel >= 99)
        {
            ch = 99;
        }else
        {
            ch = newChannel;
        }

        if(newChannel < 0)
        {
            ch = 1;
        }
    }//end of setCh
```

Should be :

```
ch = (newChannel>=99) ? 99 : ((newChannel<0) ? 1 : newChannel);
```

Comment: Avoid using the ternary condition like this. It's bad code, because it's terrible to understand and terrible to test/debug. There is also no possibility to log. A better approach is to return the new channel `public int getFilteredChannel(int channel)` and use `if(channel >= 99) return 99;`, `if(channel<0) return 1;` and `return channel`. It's much easier to read and understand unlike your nested ternary condition approach. Code size matters, but not against readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void setFlag(boolean onOffSwitch)
    {
        if(onOffSwitch == true)
        {
            flag = true;
        }else
        {
            flag = false;
        }

    }// End of setFlag
```

could be...

```
 public void setFlag(final boolean onOffSwitch)
        {
          flag = onOffSwitch;

        }// End of setFlag
```

Secondly, you have the same issue with...

```
if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("on"))
               {
                   tvStatus = true;

               }else if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("off"))
               {
                   tvStatus =false;
               }
```

could be...

```
tvStatus = x.equalsIgnoreCase("on");
```

Make your method parameters `final` as a general practice refrenced in clean code by Bob Martin.

```
if (newChannel >= 99)
        {
            ch = 99;
        }else
        {
            ch = newChannel;
        }
```

Could be...

```
ch = (newChannel>=99) ? 99 : newChannel;
```

Finally...

```
if(flag == false)
```

Would be cleaner to just do...

```
if(!flag)
```

Comment: In fact, for the tvStatus, it's not a `if ... else`, but a `if ... else if` ... so in the original code, if it's not `on` or `off` that is written, nothing happens ... So I'm not sure what you proposed is right.

Comment: It's either on or off according to the code he posted, so you could just use an else.  At least as far as the code he posted could be refactored to be so, unless it has another value other than "on" or "off".

Comment: It depends on what he wants to do ... He scans System.in. Currently on a wrong order, he decides to do nothing, neither turn his TV on or off. It can be a relevant choice.

Comment: tvstatus is defaulted to false, so if anything other than "on" is sent, it's just setting the value back to what it's set to by default.  So lets say someone enters "standby" as `x`, tvStatus will still be false.  x is never used again so all it does is set the tvstatus.

Answer (score 1):

Little modification in toString() method. Please find the below code snippets:

```
 if(flag == false)
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched","OFF","TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
    }else
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched","ON","TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
    }
```

You can check the flag directly instead of `flag==false`.

```
 if(!flag)
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched","OFF","TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
    }else if(flag)
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched","ON","TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should eliminate the duplicate return:

```
public String toString()
{
    String onOrOff = flag ? "ON" : "OFF";
    return String.format("%s :%s\n%s:%d\n%s :%d","TV is switched",onOrOff,"TV channel",ch,"TV volume",vol);
}
```

Second, I do not like C-style string formation:

```
public String toString()
{
    String onOrOff = flag ? "ON" : "OFF";
    String result = "TV is switched :" + onOrOff + '\n'
        + "TV channel:" + ch + '\n'
        + "TV volume :" + vol;
    return result;
}
```

Third, you can define an Enum:

```
enum Power { ON, OFF };
Power onOrOff = Power.ON;

public String toString()
{
    String result = "TV is switched :" + onOrOff + '\n'
        + "TV channel:" + ch + '\n'
        + "TV volume :" + vol;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I answered the original question, which was much different from the actual one. :-/